# Zend Controller Sub Directory Custom Route

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have zend controllers in following structure:

```
Application
     Controllers - folder
         AlumniAdmin - sub folder
             DashboardController.php - class name AlumniAdmin_DashbaordController

         IndexController.php
         ErrorController.php
```

I know I can access the AlumniAdmin Controller using route:
 /alumniadmin_dashboard/anyaction

But I want to access as
 /alumniadmin-dashboard/anyaction

I have used custom route in bootstrap:

```
`protected function _initRoutes()
{
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('alumniadmin-dashboard/:action/*',
                                           array('controller' => 'alumniadmin_dashboard' ));

        $router->addRoute('route', $route);
}`
```

This have 2 problems:

1. When I hit /alumniadmin-dashboard/ it is giving 404 but /alumniadmin-dashboard/index working good. Which means action must be defined.
2. I want to replace _ sign with - for all controllers. In above case I have to write explicitly each route for each controller.

Is there any idea how Can I solve above problem in better way.

Thanks!
Best Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zend route regex in order to replace _ with custom character. Refer [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex) for more details

Comment: But how It only takes first argument as Regex I need to replace _ with - :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. But may be there is more better way to do this. Following is my solution:

I have write the following Logic in Bootstrap.php.

```
`protected function _initSubDirRoutes()
{
    $subDirs = array(); $subDirPaths = array();
    $dirs = glob(APPLICATION_PATH.'/controllers/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($dirs as $dir)
        $subDirPaths[] = strtolower(preg_replace('/(.)([A-Z])/', '$1-$2', basename($dir)));

    $parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $subDirPath = $parts[3];
    if( in_array($subDirPath, $subDirPaths) )
    {
        $subDir = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords( str_replace('-',' ',$subDirPath)));
        $controllerName = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords( str_replace('-',' ',ucfirst($parts[4]))));
        $controller = $subDir.'_'.$controllerName;

        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route($subDirPath.'/'.$parts[4].'/:action/*', 
                                            array('controller'=>$controller, 
                                                  'action'=>'index'));
        $router->addRoute('route', $route);
    }
}   `
```

If user hit this url in browser **cso-admin/personal-info/users**

1. CsoAdmin is Sub Dir in Controller folder - case sensitive
2. personal-info is the name of controller in sub dir, with Class name CsoAdmin_PersonalInfoController - case sensitive
3. users is the action name